# POSTGRESQL ERROR 2F005 - brakuje instrukcji RETURN

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, return, plpgsql

I have a question, what is missing or wrong in the RETURN statement that it keeps crashing error 2F005

I am creating a table to log errors

```
    drop table if exists public.funkcja_x;
    create table public.funkcja_x 
    (
        error_alert text
    );
```

I am creating function

```
drop function if exists public.test();
create or replace function public.test()
returns text as
    $body$
 
        declare
            v_error text;
        begin

        -- i intentionally create a table from a table that doesn't exist to force an error

            drop table if exists public.tabela_final;
            create table public.tabela_final as
            select * from public.tabela_posrednia;          
 
        return 'OK';
        exception when others then 
            v_error := SQLERRM;
            insert into public.funkcja_x (error_alert) values (v_error);
        end;
    $body$
language plpgsql volatile cost 100;
alter function public.test() owner to postgres;
```

evokes:

```
select public.test();
```

and gets error:

```
BŁĄD: osiągnięto koniec funkcji, brakuje instrukcji RETURN
Stan SQL: 2F005
Kontekst: funkcja PL/pgSQL test()
```

Comment: What does the error message mean? Can you translate it to English?

Comment: ERROR: function end reached, RETURN statement missing
SQL status: 2F005
Context: PL/pgSQL test() function

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `RETURN` statement. Any non void function in PL/pgSQL should to return data. Your function uses `RETURNS text` but returns nothing. Probably miss `RETURN 'false'`.

You can use `boolean` instead text as return type.

Comment: boolean doesn't work, still getting the same error :(

Comment: @DuGi - sure - so just change from text to boolean cannot to work. You miss inside code statement `RETURN`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I found a solution, you have to replace TEXT to VOID and then it works :)
but thank you for your interest and sorry for the spam :)